# NightmareJS - Web Crawler needs to iterate over JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm building a web crawler that will cover 200+ sites. The current code I have runs on top of an external JSON file I've built of a dozen sites. Sample:

```
[
  {
    "company": "My Company",
    "url": "http://example.com/jobs/",
    "query": "div.job-listings>dt a",
    "link": "div.job-listings>dt a"
  },
  {
    "company": "Another Company",
    "url": "http://anothercompany.com/careers/",
    "query": ".clearfix~ .col-sm-6+ .col-sm-6 a , .col-sm-6:nth-child(4) a",
    "link": ".clearfix~ .col-sm-6+ .col-sm-6 a , .col-sm-6:nth-child(4) a"
  }
]
```

When I tried [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/).each it would log all of the original objects at the top of the function before attempting to enter the nightmare instance then return `error Nothing responds to "goto"`. Then I tried [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/).eachSeries, which prints out the correct result but stops after the first iteration.

```
var async = require ('async');
var data = require('./input.json')
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })

function crawl(data, cb) {
  console.log(data) // When async.each will iterate all items then error
  var nightmare = new Nightmare()
  nightmare
    .goto(data.url) // go to JSON specified url
    .wait(data.query) // wait until CSS selector loads
    .evaluate(function (data) {
      positionsArr = []
      obj = {}
      obj.company = data.company
      query = document.querySelectorAll(data.query)
      link = document.querySelectorAll(data.link)
    /* Set query and link equal to all elements with selector
    itearte through appending text (innerText) from each element
    with job url to obj*/
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    positionsObj = {}
    positionsObj.title = query[i].innerText.trim()
      // if each position has individual page
      if (data.link !== null) {
        positionsObj.url = link[i].href
      } else {
          positionsObj.url = data.url
      }
    positionsArr.push(positionsObj)
      }
      obj.positions = positionsArr
      return obj
    }, data)
  .end()
  .then(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj)
    console.log('done')
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  });
}


async.eachSeries(data, crawl, function (err){
    console.log('done!');
})
```

How can I have this work without having to write an individual file for each? Or is there a better way of crawling this amount of sites?

[Source code](https://github.com/fbongiovanni29/jawn-crawler/tree/9f264060dc33316343742c55a74b1c73fdef4aed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the callback (`cb`) if you want to execute the second step and so on:

```
.end()
.then(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log('done');
    cb();
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
    cb(error);
});
```